# Spring Properties Decryption

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption, properties

We have mix of some legacy spring apps which are not yet migrated to spring-boot or spring cloud and also spring boot apps. I am working on creating a Spring component that will automatically decrypt spring properties when the environment is loaded if the property value is encrypted and has a prefix. The properties can be in .properties files(for legacy apps) or in .yaml files(newer spring boot apps).

The component should be able to decrypt any spring property regardless of the source, and should work with any spring version and not tied to spring boot.The component should also transparently decrypt properties. It should read passphrase from a property file, so the passphrase file needs to be loaded in the beginning.

We have our own ecrypt/decrypt and don't want to use jaspyt.

Things tried so far:

I liked [this](https://github.com/lukashinsch/spring-properties-decrypter/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/hinsch/spring/propertiesdecrypter/DecryptingPropertiesApplicationListener.java) approach of creating an ApplicationListener, but this is tied up with spring boot(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent). With Spring events like ContextRefreshed or ContextStart , i don't see how can i get ConfigurableApplicationContext/ConfigurableEnvironment. Anyone created a Listener for encrypt/decrypt withouth spring boot/cloud?

I also created a custom ApplicationContextInitializer, and added it to web.xml's context-param, but this doesn't seems to be working. When i debug into it, i don't think it is loading/reading properties from my app.properties file.

```
       @Component
    public class DecryptingPropertyContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
       public void initialize( ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext ) {
          ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
          for ( PropertySource<?> propertySource : environment.getPropertySources() ) {
             Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides = new LinkedHashMap<>();
             decodePasswords( propertySource, propertyOverrides );
             if ( !propertyOverrides.isEmpty() ) {
                PropertySource<?> decodedProperties = new MapPropertySource( "decoded " + propertySource.getName(),
                      propertyOverrides );
                environment.getPropertySources().addBefore( propertySource.getName(), decodedProperties );
             }
          }
       }

        private void decodePasswords(PropertySource<?> source, Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides) {
          if ( source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource ) {
             EnumerablePropertySource<?> enumerablePropertySource = (EnumerablePropertySource<?>) source;
             for ( String key : enumerablePropertySource.getPropertyNames() ) {
                Object rawValue = source.getProperty( key );
                if ( rawValue instanceof String ) {
                   //decrypt logic here
propertyOverrides.put( key, decryptedValue );
                }
             }
          }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone had to do something similar or has any better ideas ? Is there a way i can listen to application events and then process?
Appreciate your help

Comment: you can write a custom SPEL function to decrypt.

Comment: You can try AOP and configure it to run on every call to `Proprties.load()`

Comment: @Ivan Is there a way i can listen to application events and then process?

Comment: @AkshayKhopka thanks. Like in an application events and then process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own `PropertiesFactoryBean` and override `createProperties` to decrypt encrypted values:

```
public class DecryptingPropertiesFactoryBean extends PropertiesFactoryBean {
  @Override
  protected Properties createProperties() throws IOException {
    final Properties encryptedProperties = super.createProperties();
    final Properties decryptedProperties = decrypt(encryptedProperties);
    return decryptedProperties;
  }
}
```

and a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean using these properties:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public static DecryptingPropertiesFactoryBean propertyFactory() {
    final DecryptingPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new DecryptingPropertiesFactoryBean();
    final Resource[] propertyLocations = new Resource[] {
        new FileSystemResource(new File("path/to/file.properties"))
    };
    factory.setLocations(propertyLocations);
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public static Properties properties() throws Exception {
    return propertyFactory().getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    bean.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    bean.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
    bean.setProperties(properties());
    return bean;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i'm going to try this approach. Just couple of questions, so the passphrase needs to be set in the spring environment (from spring property source files). I would need to read the passphrase(eg:encryp.passphrase) in the beginning and pass it while creating an instance of decrypter. What do you think is the best way to do this?

Comment: Considering this piece will be in a jar, how should a webapp using this PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean configured in the app to decrypt the properties?

Comment: @MaverickRiz I don't get your point about some piece being in a jar (which "piece" actually? The passphrase?). In the overridden `DecryptingPropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties` method you can do whatever you want. You can read the passphrase from the properties obtained by `super.createProperties()` read it from an environment variable or access other external resources. Whatever suits your needs.

Comment: what i mean was, i want to load the passphrase property as the first property before i do actually decrypt any other properties. So i was trying to debug but doesn't look like my app is hitting the DecryptingPropertiesFactoryBean. How do i configure app to use this bean?

Comment: I think there was an error in my example. The @Bean-methods need to be static in the special case of the property configuration.

Comment: Thank you, i will give that a shot in a bit. What do you think is a better way of loading passphrase property in the begining or first, then loop through rest of the property?

Comment: I still don't get your point? If you have the passphrase in the properties `encryptedProperties` will contain the respective property and the value can simply be read using `encryptedProperties.getProperty("notVerySecretPassphrase")`. If you want to make this more secure you'll need to get the passphrase from somewhere else. Like some external config service like Vault or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193728/discussion-between-maverick-riz-and-dpr).

Comment: I updated the example with the needed @Configuration class.

Comment: @dpr I tested your solution, by using environment object to get my encrypted property value. But the value returned is still encrypted, instead of the decrypted value