# Spring Boot application properties decrypting jpa password

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, encryption

Hi I have a Spring Boot application properties file where I configured the JPA datasource details such as username, url, password, etc. The password I have encrypted using my own encryption method from another jar file. So the password is something like

```
spring.datasource.password="ASDFIOM#KFS(@JSDF@N2"
```

I made up a random password for the sake of an example. But now I want to decrypt that password but the moment you run spring boot it opens a connection with the DB using the JPA datasource details.

How do I decrypt this password before Spring Boot makes a connection with the DB with JPA's datasource

Comment: possible duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996663/spring-properties-decryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the dataSource programmatically :

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic#configuring-a-datasource-bean

And in the line :

```
 dataSourceBuilder.password("");
```

Use your custom method to decrypt.

```
 dataSourceBuilder.password(decrypt(dbPassPropertieCrypted));
```

Comment: Beside creating our custom datasource bean in order to decrypt the password, is there other alternative? Cos creating custom datasource bean, mean i have to deal with setting url, username, etc.